# address(this).balance showing amount but msg.value not showing amount Why..?

Tags: solidity, ether

First, you see this code.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract SendAndTransferEther {
    
    event payableMessage(address _from, address _to, uint256 amount);

    receive() external payable {}

    function checkBalance() public payable returns(uint) {
        return  address(this).balance;
    }

    function checkBalanceMsg() external payable returns(uint) {
        return msg.value;
    }
}
```

When I send 5 Ether, after that, I call the **checkBalance()** function it shows 5 Ether, but when I call **checkBalanceMsg()** function it shows **0 ether**. I'm a little bit confused, What am I doing wrong.?

**Look at the output.**

[image: Output of above code]

Answer (score 0):

I feel you forgot to set the `value` from the remix menu. That's why the value of `msg.value` is showing zero. As the `checkBalanceMsg`function has been marked `payable`, you need to send the value from the remix menu.

Lmk if doesn't get resolved by this.

[image]

Comment: If I don't set any value then how do I get the value this **checkBalance()**. Please see I'm output image.

Comment: The CheckBalance() function checks the balance of the smart contract, it returns whatever smart contract holds. Whereas the checkBalanceMsg() function returns the value that has been passed with the transaction and not the smart contract balance. Both functionalities are different.

Comment: @NgSharma I hope the above comment clears your confusion.

Comment: Okay, Its mean **address(this).balance** and **msg.value** are two different things.

Comment: Yeah! `address(this).balance` returns the ether balance of the contract while `msg.value` is the amount sent along with the transaction.

Comment: but I'm passing a value

Comment: the function returns the value of `msg.value` not the amount.

Comment: Does this answer your question?